# I'm using Visual Studio 2019 and I'm currently making some equation about body height and weight in C, is this a close resemblance or not?

Tags: c

I just want to know if I made any mistakes (which is very likely considering there are 11 warnings and multiple green lines on my code.)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main(void) 

{

    int heightBody, weightBody, heightAndWeightResult; // Variables

    printf("Enter Body Weight: ", weightBody); //Manual Input
    scanf_s("%d", &weightBody);

    printf("Enter Body Height: ", heightBody);// Manual Input
    scanf_s("%d", &heightBody);

    heightAndWeightResult = heightBody + weightBody; // to calculate the height and weight
    printf("Body Result: ", heightAndWeightResult);

    getch();
    return 0;

}
```

Regarding of error messages, there is the "Too many arguments" error; using Uninitialized memory; and Return value ignored getch();

Comment: @ReticulatedSpline no, this is not suited to code review as code review requires that the program works and this one doesn't.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala My bad. I attempted to edit my comment to make it clear that this program needed work first, but I had already crossed the five minute mark. I'll keep that in mind in the future.

Answer (score 1):

1. Give the variables initial values

i.e.

```
int heightBody = 0, weightBody = 0, heightAndWeightResult;
```

2. Check the return value from `scanf_s` - Read the manual page for that
3. Do not need the variable in the first two `printf`

i.e.

```
 printf("Enter Body Weight: "); 
 printf("Enter Body Height: ");
```

4. Need a format specifier in the last `printf`

i.e.

```
 printf("Body Result: %d", heightAndWeightResult);
```

*Perhaps it would be worthwhile for you to read the manual pages for `printf` and `scanf_s`*

Comment: And `getch()`...

Comment: @Juaquin - then mark it correct and/or +1 it